# Decryption a Picture using CryptoJS and Inserting it into a Page

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

For a slew of complicated reasons. we need to send images over the network in encrypted state and decrypt them on the other side using AES. On the server side here is what happens:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in pup.jpg -out pup.jpg.enc
base64 pup.jpg.enc > pup.jpg.enc.b64
```

On the client side here is the JavaScript we are using:

```
<img id="picture"/>
<script>
    var picture = document.getElementById("picture");
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open('GET', 'http://server.com/pup.jpg.enc.b64', true);
    data.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200){
            var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.responseText, "password");
            var plain = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify( dec );
        picture.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+plain;
        }
    };
    data.send(null);
</script>
```

I am getting a deviation in the input and output, and I can not figure out why, for the life of me. Here is the input and output:

```
In:  /9j/4RLKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABBADJx...
Out: /9j/4RLKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABBAAAA...
                                               ^-- deviation
```

Do I have to specify to the CryptoJS that I am using 256bit encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with a bug in CryptoJS that causes the library to not work if input string contains new lines. Encoding the file like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in pup.jpg -pass pass:"password" | base64 | tr -d '\n' > pup.enc
```

fixes the issue. The problem want with the javascript, but with the encoding. Well, and with javascript, because there is a bug in cryptojs: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=38

Answer (score 0):

From the CryptoJS documentation, it mentions the output of AES.decrypt is the same type as the output of a hash function. In [the Hasher Output section](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output) there is an example of converting this WordArray to a base 64 encoded string:

```
    alert(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); // L3dmip37+NWEi57rSnFFypTG7ZI25Kdz9tyvpRMrL5E=
```

Comment: I tried that before actually, but I can not make it work. It actually works, at first, but then the input and output start to deviate. Input: "/9j/4RLKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABBADJx" Output:
"/9j/4RLKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABBAAAA". It starts out right, but then deviates. Can not figure out why. I am going to add this to the question.